# merge sort understanding recursion

Tags: c, recursion, merge, mergesort, logarithm

I want to understand how does it work like I have this thing.

```
void merge_sort(int *a, int first, int last)
{
    int middle;
    if (first < last)
    {
        middle = (first + last) / 2;
        merge_sort(a, first, middle);    // 1
        merge_sort(a, middle + 1, last); // 2
        merge(a, first, middle, last);   // 3
    }
}
```

how does it work like if have an array of `3,4,2,1,5` it will first cut it in half from <--middle side and only then it will go to line 2-`merge_sort(a, middle+1, last);` and it will restart first and last until the condition is made and then it will go to line 3 like does all that stuff happen one after another or does it all happen at the same time all the 3 lines?

Comment: No, your initial understanding is correct - there is no parallel processing going on here.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError instead, help him in such a way that he will not need explanation anymore from now on as for this topic.

Comment: **Most people don't know how multiple recursion works. They just follow stack traces or debugging on ides. So, don't worry if you don't understand it. Further, they cannot write a multiple recursion to solve problems, but interestingly debug written ones and try to understand them even if they forget a couple of hours later** Some years I've been here, I haven't run into a guy that explains it very well in a way that you will never need to ask it again. There are really a few guys know how to do this job, but they hide the art because they want to take it when they're in their graves.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sorts the first half, then it sorts the 2nd half and then it merges the two sorted parts together.  This happens sequentially.  The two recursive merge_sort() calls could happen in parallel (as they are non-overlapping) but it doesn't in this implementation.